# SWI-Prolog: Use operators from modules?

Tags: module, prolog, operator-keyword

I have a prolog-file (name definitions.pl) of this kind of type:

```
:- module(definitions,[]).

:-op(699, xfx, :=).
:-op(599, xfy, ∪).



C := (A ∪ B) :- union(A, B, C).
```

My aim is to use this file as module in another file test.pl. To integrate it I tried:

```
:-use_module(definitions).
```

But for some reason its not possible to make statements like:

```
X:=[1,2]∪[3,4].
```

after loading test.pl into swipl. I also tried:

```
:- module(definitions,[:=/2, ∪/2]).

:-op(699, xfx, :=).
:-op(599, xfy, ∪).
```

but this gives some `operator exprected` error. What is the correct way to use operators in prolog-modules?

Comment: Assuming from your previous question, you are using SWI. There operators are local to a module unless you declare them in the interface. See some existing library like `clpfd.pl`. However, I do not think that what you are doing is a good idea. At least try to fit priorities into the existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the operator definitions into the module export list:

```
:- module(definitions, [
    (:=)/2, op(699, xfx, :=),
    op(599, xfy, ∪)
]).

:- use_module(library(lists), [union/3]).

C := (A ∪ B) :-
    union(A, B, C).
```

Usage example (assuming a `definitions.pl` file with the above contents in the current working directory):

```
?- use_module(definitions).
true.

?- X:=[1,2]∪[3,4].
X = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```